# Create file system/container if not found

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to export a CSV to an Azure Data Lake Storage but when the file system/container does not exist the code breaks. I have also read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python) but I cannot seem to find anything helpful for this situation.

How do I go about creating a container in Azure Data Lake Storage if the container specified by the user does not exist?

**Current Code:**

```
    try:
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="testfilesystem")
    except Exception:
        file_system_client = service_client.create_file_system(file_system="testfilesystem")
```

**Traceback:**

```
(FilesystemNotFound) The specified filesystem does not exist.
RequestId:XXXX
Time:2021-03-31T13:39:21.8860233Z
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback

Comment: that's the entire thing that gets returned when I run the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `try catch` pattern should be not used here since the `Azure Data lake gen2 library` has the built in `exists() method` for `file_system_client`.

First, make sure you've installed **the latest version library**: [azure-storage-file-datalake 12.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake/). If you're not sure which version you're using, please use `pip show azure-storage-file-datalake` command to check the current version.

Then you can use the code below:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
           "https", "xxx"), credential="xxx")

#the get_file_system_client method will not throw error if the file system does not exist, if you're using the latest library 12.3.0
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client("filesystem333")

print("the file system exists: " + str(file_system_client.exists()))

#create the file system if it does not exist
if not file_system_client.exists():
    file_system_client.create_file_system()
    print("the file system is created.")

#other code
```

I've tested it locally, it can work successfully:

[image]